# Проблемы с наследованием !important свойств в CSS

Tags: css, наследование

Праздно ковыряя CSS заметил странный момент.

Стиль body заданный с `!important` игнорируется браузером и определяется стиль указанный обычным способом. Насколько мне известно, наследуемые свойства с этой инструкцией обладают высшим приоритетом наследования не считая `<style>`.

Есть исключения или я что-то пропустил?

[image: Скрин1]
[image: Скрин2]

Comment: СДелайте ваш код исполняемым. Что-то мне подсказывает, что у вас в коде банальная очепятка.

Comment: [Вот сделал](https://jsfiddle.net/95ceewoa/). Собственно заголовок наследует, абзац - нет.

Comment: Забыл указать стиль для абзаца, теперь оба не наследуют. Отчего так?

Comment: стиль для заголовка*

Answer (score 3):

Применяя `!important` вы повышаете приоритет текущего селектора. При этом импортант никак не влияет на правила наследования стилей для дочерних элементов.

Например, если у вас на странице есть где-то выше вашего кода стиль:

```
body#dumbid{color: orange;}
```

И вы не можете никак его изменить или как-то поменять разметку, чтобы избавиться от него, то в таком крайнем случае можно применить `!important` для переопределения, либо дублировать селектор для уравнивания приоритета.

```
body{color: blue !important;}
```

Так вы только нейтрализовали стиль селектор `body#dumbid`, но никак не изменили правила наследования для дочерних элементов.

В вашем случае не важно есть `!important` или нет у стиля боди. Селектор `p` будет более приоритетным так как является более специфичным.